# Generate lat long along a line

Tags: python, python-2.7, coordinates

I need to find the co-ordinates (lat/long) nearer to some other co-ordinate by some percentage of the distance between those two co-ordinates.

Example:

```
location1 = (32.7991094663, -117.234719251)
location2 = (32.7094778234, -117.136413578)

# find a new location closer by 60% from location1 than location2
find_closer_location(location1, location2, 60)
```

for calculating distance i am using below algo

```
from math import radians, cos, sin, asin, sqrt


def haversine(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2):
    # convert decimal degrees to radians 
    lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(radians, [lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2])
    dlon = lon2 - lon1 
    dlat = lat2 - lat1 
    a = sin(dlat/2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon/2)**2
    c = 2 * asin(sqrt(a)) 
    km = 6371 * c
    return km
```

Comment: Percentage of what?

Comment: Ken Syme, Percentage of distance between two co-ordinates

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly. You have 2 points. And you want to move one of the points closer to the other point by 60%

Comment: tisaconundrum, yes

Comment: Could you specify what point you want to be moving?

Comment: What distance method are you using? The Earth is not flat, so how the spherical nature is modelled matters for the distance calculation. See [here](https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) for details, and some code snippets (for javascript) to get started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for every one's effort.

Finally I think I have a solution.

```
from math import radians, cos, sin, asin, sqrt, atan2, degrees, log, tan, pi

R = 6378.1  #Radius of the Earth in km


def get_distance(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2):
    # convert decimal degrees to radians 
    lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(radians, [lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2])
    dlon = lon2 - lon1
    dlat = lat2 - lat1 
    a = sin(dlat/2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon/2)**2
    c = 2 * asin(sqrt(a)) 
    km = R * c
    return km


def calculateBearing(lat1, lng1, lat2, lng2):
    '''calculates the azimuth in degrees from start point to end point'''
    startLat = radians(lat1)
    startLong = radians(lng1)
    endLat = radians(lat2)
    endLong = radians(lng2)
    dLong = endLong - startLong
    dPhi = log(tan(endLat/2.0+pi/4.0)/tan(startLat/2.0+pi/4.0))
    if abs(dLong) > pi:
         if dLong > 0.0:
             dLong = -(2.0 * pi - dLong)
         else:
             dLong = (2.0 * pi + dLong)
    bearing = (degrees(atan2(dLong, dPhi)) + 360.0) % 360.0;
    return bearing


def getDestinationLatLong(lat, lng, azimuth, d):
    '''returns the lat an long of destination point 
    given the start lat, long, aziuth, and distance'''
    brng = radians(azimuth) #Bearing is degrees converted to radians.
    lat1 = radians(lat) #Current dd lat point converted to radians
    lon1 = radians(lng) #Current dd long point converted to radians
    lat2 = asin(sin(lat1) * cos(d/R) + cos(lat1)* sin(d/R)* cos(brng))
    lon2 = lon1 + atan2(sin(brng) * sin(d/R)* cos(lat1), cos(d/R)- sin(lat1)* sin(lat2))
    #convert back to degrees
    lat2 = degrees(lat2)
    lon2 = degrees(lon2)
    return[lat2, lon2]


location1 = (32.7991094663, -117.234719251)
location2 = (32.7094778234, -117.136413578)
percentage = 60

distance = get_distance(location1[1], location1[0], location2[1], location2[0])
print distance
new_distance = distance - (distance * percentage / 100)
print new_distance
azimuth = calculateBearing(location1[0], location1[1], location2[0], location2[1])
coords = getDestinationLatLong(location1[0], location1[1], azimuth, new_distance)
print coords
```

Reference: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/157693/getting-all-vertex-lat-long-coordinates-every-1-meter-between-two-known-points

Answer (score -1):

Compute it:

```
def moveMe(t1,t2,perc):
    x1, y1= t1  # location1 = (32.7991094663, -117.234719251)
    x2, y2 = t2 # location2 = (32.7094778234, -117.136413578)

    dx = (x2-x1) / 100.0 * perc
    dy = (y2-y1) / 100.0 * perc

    return (x1+dx,y1+dy)

location1 = (32.7991094663, -117.234719251)
location2 = (32.7094778234, -117.136413578)
print(moveMe(location1,location2,10))
```

Output:

```
(32.808072630590004, -117.2445498183)
```

This interpolates a new point on the line between (and beyond for `perc` `<0` or `>100`)  `t1` and `t2` by `perc`ent. If you want points away from that line you would have to get somewhat more creative.

Comment: The Earth isn't flat!

Comment: with `(10, 10)` and `(15, 15)` 20 percent of the way there is not `(9, 9)`.. you should also not encourage low quality questions.

Comment: @sayse fixed it - why do you conisder it a low quality question? If you take every question posted here and eliminate those that can be solved by thinking , googling or SO research, almost none will be left.

Comment: @KenSyme - well, he did not define that the distance is measured over the ground. You are assuming he wants to halve the distance "as traveled over ground" ?

Comment: @PatrickArtner - Because the op hasn't applied any of their own effort into solving their problem. ["we are trying to build something that benefits the world at large, not just the one person having the problem."](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315040/1324033)

Comment: @Sayse I can see your point. But - nicknack aside - this question presents all that is needed for "a" answer. It wont be a answer for KenSyme who obviously is far deeper int the matter of distance measureing on an earthy scale then I am. The question is, does the questioniear need that much complexity or is he just not able to compute a distancedelta and get a percentage from it (like my 1st post). So I learned smth, he learned smth. Someone might change the title to "How to interpolate a point n% between two other points for lat/long coords?" so its better searchable and can be found by othrs